# How to smooth out faces of circular object?

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible to smooth out the faces on the right shape to make it look similar as the shape on the left?

As you can see, the shape on the right still has the edges visible and the shape on the left does not. I don't want to have edges on the shape on the right. I want a smooth surface just as the shape on the left.

I tried shade smooth, but that doesn't give me the result I want.
Important to note, I created these from a shape in Object Mode and added a circle in Edit mode, so it's still one object in Object Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To keep some angles sharp and others smooth you need to select "Auto Smooth" and adjust the threshold. Value of 30 is usually good enough, but in some cases I had to set it to 60.

[image: Setting Auto Smooth]

Comment: You could also select the top and bottom, switch to edge selection mode, and then right-click, mark as sharp. Now you can set a very big angle, so it's not used, just the sharpness.